# Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, dom, ui-automation

I was not able to access IE elements from SHDOCvw.Internetexplorer ie object.  Below is my code.

```
 //Manipulating HTML element

            HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)ie.Document;    

            Console.WriteLine("Setting text box to google search text box");
            IHTMLElement element = document.getElementById("lst-ib");
```

Any suggestions ? The error i get is

```
  '((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)(document)).activeElement' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
```

Tried below but get the same error.

```
IHTMLDocument2 d = (IHTMLDocument2)ie.Document;
```

Complete code is here:

```
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = null;
            Console.WriteLine("\nLaunching an instance of IE");
            Process p = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", www.google.com);
            if (p == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not launch IE");
            Console.WriteLine("Process handle = " + p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
            SHDocVw.ShellWindows allBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
            Console.WriteLine("Number active browsers = " + allBrowsers.Count);
            if (allBrowsers.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Cannot find IE");
            Console.WriteLine("Attaching to IE");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < allBrowsers.Count && ie == null)
            {
            InternetExplorer e = (InternetExplorer)allBrowsers.Item(i);
            if (e.HWND == (int)p.MainWindowHandle)
            ie = e;
            ++i;
            }
            if (ie == null)
            throw new Exception("Failed to attach to IE");
             HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)ie.Document;               
             IHTMLDocument2 d = (IHTMLDocument2)ie.Document;

             Console.WriteLine("Setting text box to google search text box");
             IHTMLElement element = document.getElementById("lst-ib");
             The above line is the one which throws the error:
            "Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'"
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but have you tried `ie.DomDocument`?

Comment: I could fix that error  with activeElement. There was a timing issue.But not able to fix "Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'. "

Comment: More code would be helpful.  In particular, you appear to be merging unmanaged interfaces from mshtml.dll (in particular, `SHDOCvw.Internetexplorer` and the `WebBrowser` control from `system.windows.forms`).

Comment: @EricBrown Added more lines of code

Comment: I got it worked by using IHTMLDocument3 casting on ie.Document instead of IHTMLDocument. Not sure why one works and other one doesn't. Does IHTMLDocument3 has all the capabilities of IHTMLDocument for ie test automation ?

 IHTMLDocument3 d = (IHTMLDocument3)ie.Document;
 Console.WriteLine("Setting text box to google search text box");
 HTMLInputElement element = (HTMLInputElement)document.getElementById("lst-ib");

Comment: @krrishna that works for me. It should be an answer in my opinion.